# @MockBean seems to rerun context creation and fails afterMigrate.sql

Tags: java, spring, mockito, flyway, spring-test

I have two integration test classes. One of these classes depends on the bean that is talking to external service, so I need to mock this bean, and `@MockBean` seems perfect for this. For injecting some seeds into DB I'm using `flyway`'s `afterMigrate.sql`. So here is hot it looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Rollback
class FooTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Rollback
class BarTest {

  @MockBean
  private ExternalService;

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;
}
```

And `afterMigrate.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) VALUES (1, 'John Doe')
```

The problem appeared when I annotate the `ExternatService` as `@MockBean` as now the `afretMigrate.sql` runs twice and I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
....
Message    : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey"
```

When I'm changing the `@MockBean` to `@Autowired` the error is gone and context is created without any problems. Also, tests run without problems if I run `BarTest` separately.
This is not the expected behavior for `@MockBean` as the documentation says:

> Any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context will
>   be replaced by the mock. If no existing bean is defined a new one will
>   be added. Dependencies that are known to the application context but
>   are not beans (such as those registered directly) will not be found
>   and a mocked bean will be added to the context alongside the existing
>   dependency.

It does not say that the context will be recreated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I have resolved this issue (which I consider an issue).

**Solution 1:**
I have created a `MockConfig` class with that should create one `mock` for entire test suite:

```
@Configration
public class MockConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ExternalService externalService() {
    return mock(ExternalService.class);
  }
}
```

And in the test, I'm just autowiring the external service:

```
@Autowire
private ExternalService externalService;
```

But this solution has a problem, it will create a real bean then will override it with the mock bean. If your external service make a connection to the external resources on creation, and you don't need that then you will need another solution.

**Solution 2:**
Create a basic abstract class with `@MockBean` in it:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Rollback
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {
  @MockBean
  ExternalService externalService;
}
```

And extend the integration test from this base class:

```
class FooTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;
}

class BarTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;
}
```

Now the context won't refresh as it's always the same, and the real bean won't be created.

Answer (score 8):

Because when you use `@MockBean` annotation your context will be loaded for each test. Please refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10015). The citation from this page :

> The Spring test framework will cache an ApplicationContext whenever possible between test runs. In order to be cached, the context must have an exactly equivalent configuration. Whenever you use @MockBean, you are by definition changing the context configuration.

So when you use your mock  bean in different tests - the context will be recreated each time for your test class. So if you for example have some beans that load data to DB on context creation - for example beans for flyway - they will be created each time context is recreated.